# Retrieving values from an rhandsontable object (R, R shiny)

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, rhandsontable

I use the (awesome) package rhandsontable that will later be included in an **R** shiny webpage. The user can click at some places, and I want to know how to retrieve the info on which rows was clicked. 
Here is an example, (to be copy&paste in an **R** terminal):

```
library(rhandsontable)

## Create the dataset
min = c(1,seq(2,34,by=2))
kmh = c(0,seq(7,23,by=1))
mph = round( kmh / 1.609344, digits=0 )
stop.speed = rep(FALSE, length(min))    
DF = data.frame(min, kmh, mph, stop.speed, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#plot the table
r = rhandsontable(DF, useTypes = TRUE)
```

I thought about converting it to an **R** object:

```
hot_to_r(r)

Error in (function (data, changes, params, ...)  : 
argument "params" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is 4 years old, but still relevant for the `rhandsontable` package users. Also, the solution provided by Lyx above no longer works. Following is an easy fix to the problem.

Every `rhandsontable` object is a deeply nested list. One of its elements is the `data` element, which itself is nested under the `x` element. However, the data is in `json` format, but it can easily be converted to a `data.frame` by using the `fromJSON()` function in the `jsonlite` package.

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(jsonlite)

hands_on_table <- rhandsontable(mtcars)
data_frame <- fromJSON(hands_on_table$x$data)
head(data_frame)

   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Edit:

It is important to also mention that the main difference between using `hot_to_r` and `jsonlite::fromJSON` is that the former is used while the app is running and the latter only works in an interactive R session.

Answer (score 2):

Besides shinysky, another solution is call back the handsontable:

server.R

```
DF = hot_to_r(input$table)
```

in the ui.R, table had been called using:

```
rHandsontableOutput("table")
```

DF can then be used as any R data frame

Comment: After reading above answers, I was about to reply to this post and to say "just use `hot_to_r` but found your answer at the very last, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Once in the shiny app you can use:

```
input$table_select$select$r # access the row number
input$table_select$select$c # access the column number
input$table_select$data[[input$table_select$select$r]][[input$table_select$select$c]] # access the data in a cell
```

You could write a small function to 'translate' the row and column number into a position in your dataframe/matrix/etc, or just access the value as above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: works fine, just need to add `selectCallback = TRUE` to `rhandsontable()`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `shinysky` package. Note that I show the table with the implemented changes also so you can check your work

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinysky)

## Create the dataset
min = c(1,seq(2,34,by=2))
kmh = c(0,seq(7,23,by=1))
mph = round( kmh / 1.609344, digits=0 )
stop.speed = rep(FALSE, length(min))    
DF = data.frame(min, kmh, mph, stop.speed, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Initiate your table
  previous <- reactive({DF})

  MyChanges <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$hotable1)){return(previous())}
    else if(!identical(previous(),input$hotable1)){
      # hot.to.df function will convert your updated table into the dataframe
      as.data.frame(hot.to.df(input$hotable1))
    }
  })
  output$hotable1 <- renderHotable({MyChanges()}, readOnly = F)
  # You can see the changes you made
  output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(MyChanges())
})

ui <- basicPage(mainPanel(column(6,hotable("hotable1")),column(6,DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'))))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that detailed example. So you create a DF, then create a table out of it, then check that it has changed and create a DF out of it, right? Regarding my initial question, I can now retrieve the changed rows by doing: "MyChanges[which(MyChanges$stop.speed == TRUE),]", is that correct?

Comment: Looks like the ShinySky package does not fit with the latest R version
package ‘shinysky’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1) 
same error for R 3.2.4

Comment: I'm on R version 3.1.3 and `shinysky` version 0.1.2

Answer (score 1):

You can install shinysky package in r 3.3.1 by following the below mentioned steps :-

```
install.packages("devtools") 
devtools::install_github("AnalytixWare/ShinySky")
```

---