# `hot_to_r()` function from `rhandsontable` package not working inside a "normal" .R script - how do you check the aspect of your datas inside shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am trying to understand how `hot_to_r()` convert the list object obtained with `rhandsontable()`. My goal is to see the object that you get after `hot_to_r()` processes in order to debug a shiny app.

However, it seems that you can not do this outside the shiny app *i.e* inside a .R script.

[EDIT] searching further leads me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56410707/10264278) post.
Are we sure that the object that you get from `fromJSON()` is the same as the one from `hot_to_r()`

Here is a .R script I was trying to use to see the output of `hot_to_r()`:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

# dummy dataframe
df = data.frame(id = c("a", "b"),
                val = c(0.75, 0.25))

# convert it to a "rhansontable" object
test = rhandsontable(df)

# try to convert it back to a dataframe but it doesn't work
test_hot = hot_to_r(test)

# however, this works but I am not sure if test_json is the same as test_hot
test_json = fromJSON(test$x$data)
```

`test_hot = hot_to_r(test)` leads to this error:

> test_df = hot_to_r(test)
>
> Error in (function (data, changes, params, ...)  :    argument "params" is missing, with no default

I am very new to shiny ; am I missing something?

Is it normal that you can not get `hot_to_r()` work inside a .R script?

If yes, how do you check the "aspect" of your data inside the shiny app?
The overall goal is to make calculations with a rhandsontable filled by users. I want to transform this object into a dataframe in order to make the correct modifications to get a "tidy" dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hot_to_r` is intended to be used with a shiny input (which contains the `params` argument mentioned in the error message).

For debugging in the shiny context I'd recommend using `browser()`.

Please check the following:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("myTable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # dummy dataframe
  df = data.frame(id = c("a", "b"),
                  val = c(0.75, 0.25), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # convert it to a "rhansontable" object
  output$myTable <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(df)})

  observeEvent(input$myTable, {
    test_df = hot_to_r(input$myTable)
    print(test_df)
    # browser() # uncomment for debugging
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, `fromJSON` also is a valid approach.